# Cannot connect to one specific WiFi SSID (an eero router); have connected to others without problem, have connected to this SSID w other devices

Tags: wifi, elementary-os

Running Elementary OS 5.1.6 (Hera), trying to connect to an eero router via WiFi. I put in the correct password (I have checked and re-entered the password literally a dozen times now), click Connect, and it looks like it's trying to authenticate but fails. I can:

- connect to the eero via wired connection on this machine
- connect to every other wifi ssid i've ever attempted on this machine
- connect via wifi to this router on Android, MacOS, and Windows devices of all kinds
- see the connection in the eero app (I've checked that it's the wireless LAN adapter, not the wired), and it's listed as idle.

here's the `/var/log/syslog` from my most recent attempts. I've used the native network manager and wicd. I have deleted the backported Intel network drivers.

```
Jul 12 14:38:38 moooo io.elementary.s[7578]: g_bytes_compare: assertion 'bytes1 != NULL' failed
Jul 12 14:38:38 moooo nm-applet[2838]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jul 12 14:38:38 moooo nm-applet[2838]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jul 12 14:38:38 moooo nm-applet[2838]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jul 12 14:38:38 moooo nm-applet[2838]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jul 12 14:38:38 moooo nm-applet[2838]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jul 12 14:38:38 moooo nm-applet[2838]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594586322.2893] device (wlp2s0): Activation: starting connection '<ssid-name>' (2d300e81-ad8d-42b6-a3d2-7c13c8868ed0)
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594586322.2896] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="2d300e81-ad8d-42b6-a3d2-7c13c8868ed0" name="<ssid-name>" pid=2754 uid=1000 result="success"
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594586322.2900] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594586322.2909] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594586322.2912] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) access point '<ssid-name>' has security, but secrets are required.
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594586322.2913] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594586322.2980] device (wlp2s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594586322.2986] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594586322.2989] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) connection '<ssid-name>' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594586322.2989] Config: added 'ssid' value '<ssid-name>'
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594586322.2990] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594586322.2990] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-80:86400'
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594586322.2990] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594586322.2990] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594586322.2990] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo io.elementary.s[7578]: network_widgets_settings_button_check_sensitive: assertion 'self != NULL' failed
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo wpa_supplicant[1159]: wlp2s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 4c:01:43:ea:d4:06 (SSID='<ssid-name>' freq=2412 MHz)
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo kernel: [ 2757.327632] wlp2s0: authenticate with 4c:01:43:ea:d4:06
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo nm-applet[2838]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo kernel: [ 2757.334113] wlp2s0: send auth to 4c:01:43:ea:d4:06 (try 1/3)
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo nm-applet[2838]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594586322.3222] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> authenticating
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo wpa_supplicant[1159]: wlp2s0: Trying to associate with 4c:01:43:ea:d4:06 (SSID='<ssid-name>' freq=2412 MHz)
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo kernel: [ 2757.337687] wlp2s0: authenticated
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo kernel: [ 2757.338411] wlp2s0: associate with 4c:01:43:ea:d4:06 (try 1/3)
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo kernel: [ 2757.342113] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 4c:01:43:ea:d4:06 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594586322.3314] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo nm-applet[2838]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo kernel: [ 2757.362048] wlp2s0: associated
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo wpa_supplicant[1159]: wlp2s0: Associated with 4c:01:43:ea:d4:06
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo wpa_supplicant[1159]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo wpa_supplicant[1159]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=US
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594586322.3555] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo nm-applet[2838]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo nm-applet[2838]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jul 12 14:38:42 moooo nm-applet[2838]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jul 12 14:38:47 moooo kernel: [ 2762.451570] wlp2s0: deauthenticated from 4c:01:43:ea:d4:06 (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
Jul 12 14:38:47 moooo wpa_supplicant[1159]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=4c:01:43:ea:d4:06 reason=2
Jul 12 14:38:47 moooo wpa_supplicant[1159]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="<ssid-name>" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED
Jul 12 14:38:47 moooo wpa_supplicant[1159]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Jul 12 14:38:47 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <warn>  [1594586327.4984] sup-iface[0x5629e4645990,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason 2)
Jul 12 14:38:47 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594586327.5036] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
Jul 12 14:38:47 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594586327.6030] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul 12 14:38:47 moooo io.elementary.s[7578]: g_bytes_compare: assertion 'bytes1 != NULL' failed
Jul 12 14:38:47 moooo nm-applet[2838]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jul 12 14:38:47 moooo nm-applet[2838]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jul 12 14:38:47 moooo nm-applet[2838]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jul 12 14:38:47 moooo nm-applet[2838]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jul 12 14:38:47 moooo nm-applet[2838]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jul 12 14:38:47 moooo nm-applet[2838]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jul 12 14:38:58 moooo wpa_supplicant[1159]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="<ssid-name>"
Jul 12 14:38:58 moooo wpa_supplicant[1159]: wlp2s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 80:da:13:1e:5e:63 (SSID='<ssid-name>' freq=2412 MHz)
Jul 12 14:38:58 moooo kernel: [ 2773.176456] wlp2s0: authenticate with 80:da:13:1e:5e:63
Jul 12 14:38:58 moooo kernel: [ 2773.179379] wlp2s0: send auth to 80:da:13:1e:5e:63 (try 1/3)
Jul 12 14:38:58 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594586338.1704] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jul 12 14:38:58 moooo wpa_supplicant[1159]: wlp2s0: Trying to associate with 80:da:13:1e:5e:63 (SSID='<ssid-name>' freq=2412 MHz)
Jul 12 14:38:58 moooo kernel: [ 2773.184915] wlp2s0: authenticated
Jul 12 14:38:58 moooo kernel: [ 2773.186023] wlp2s0: associate with 80:da:13:1e:5e:63 (try 1/3)
Jul 12 14:38:58 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594586338.1806] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jul 12 14:38:58 moooo kernel: [ 2773.190882] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 80:da:13:1e:5e:63 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=4)
Jul 12 14:38:58 moooo nm-applet[2838]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jul 12 14:38:58 moooo nm-applet[2838]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jul 12 14:38:58 moooo wpa_supplicant[1159]: wlp2s0: Associated with 80:da:13:1e:5e:63
Jul 12 14:38:58 moooo wpa_supplicant[1159]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jul 12 14:38:58 moooo wpa_supplicant[1159]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=US
Jul 12 14:38:58 moooo kernel: [ 2773.210746] wlp2s0: associated
Jul 12 14:38:58 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594586338.2151] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Jul 12 14:38:58 moooo io.elementary.s[7578]: network_widgets_settings_button_check_sensitive: assertion 'self != NULL' failed
Jul 12 14:38:58 moooo nm-applet[2838]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jul 12 14:38:58 moooo nm-applet[2838]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jul 12 14:38:58 moooo nm-applet[2838]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jul 12 14:38:58 moooo nm-applet[2838]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jul 12 14:39:03 moooo kernel: [ 2778.300464] wlp2s0: deauthenticated from 80:da:13:1e:5e:63 (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
Jul 12 14:39:03 moooo wpa_supplicant[1159]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=80:da:13:1e:5e:63 reason=2
Jul 12 14:39:03 moooo wpa_supplicant[1159]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="<ssid-name>" auth_failures=2 duration=20 reason=CONN_FAILED
Jul 12 14:39:03 moooo wpa_supplicant[1159]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Jul 12 14:39:03 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <warn>  [1594586343.3587] sup-iface[0x5629e4645990,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason 2)
Jul 12 14:39:03 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594586343.3638] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
Jul 12 14:39:03 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594586343.4638] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul 12 14:39:04 moooo nm-applet[2838]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jul 12 14:39:04 moooo nm-applet[2838]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jul 12 14:39:04 moooo nm-applet[2838]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jul 12 14:39:04 moooo nm-applet[2838]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jul 12 14:39:04 moooo nm-applet[2838]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jul 12 14:39:04 moooo nm-applet[2838]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jul 12 14:39:07 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <warn>  [1594586347.1893] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long
Jul 12 14:39:07 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594586347.1894] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 12 14:39:07 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <warn>  [1594586347.1945] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) asking for new secrets
Jul 12 14:39:07 moooo nm-applet[2838]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jul 12 14:39:07 moooo nm-applet[2838]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jul 12 14:39:07 moooo nm-applet[2838]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jul 12 14:39:07 moooo nm-applet[2838]: No keyring secrets found for <ssid-name>/802-11-wireless-security; asking user.
Jul 12 14:39:07 moooo nm-applet[2838]: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Jul 12 14:39:07 moooo dbus-daemon[1086]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.79' (uid=1000 pid=2838 comm="nm-applet " label="unconfined")
Jul 12 14:39:07 moooo systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Jul 12 14:39:07 moooo dbus-daemon[1086]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Jul 12 14:39:07 moooo systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem went away after a whole day of frustrating research, but without any clear reason. I went into Advanced Settings under the wired connection, while wired to the eero pro, and all of a sudden the wifi connected, and has stayed connected even after disconnecting the wired. If you're having this problem, try that! It might help!

**UPDATE:** This connection survived my machine going to sleep once, but not twice. The next morning it was back to the old brokenness.

Here's what i think are the relevant syslog entries from when it succeeded:

```
Jul 12 16:59:24 moooo kernel: [ 4662.718436] wlp2s0: deauthenticated from 4c:01:43:ea:d4:06 (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
Jul 12 16:59:24 moooo wpa_supplicant[1159]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=4c:01:43:ea:d4:06 reason=2
Jul 12 16:59:24 moooo wpa_supplicant[1159]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Jul 12 16:59:24 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <warn>  [1594594764.7286] sup-iface[0x5629e479b390,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason 2)
Jul 12 16:59:24 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594594764.7335] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
Jul 12 16:59:24 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594594764.8336] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul 12 16:59:24 moooo wpa_supplicant[1159]: wlp2s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 80:da:13:1e:5e:63 (SSID='<ssid-name>' freq=2412 MHz)
Jul 12 16:59:24 moooo kernel: [ 4662.923535] wlp2s0: authenticate with 80:da:13:1e:5e:63
Jul 12 16:59:24 moooo kernel: [ 4662.925938] wlp2s0: send auth to 80:da:13:1e:5e:63 (try 1/3)
Jul 12 16:59:24 moooo kernel: [ 4662.929050] wlp2s0: authenticated
Jul 12 16:59:24 moooo wpa_supplicant[1159]: wlp2s0: Trying to associate with 80:da:13:1e:5e:63 (SSID='<ssid-name>' freq=2412 MHz)
Jul 12 16:59:24 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594594764.8747] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jul 12 16:59:24 moooo kernel: [ 4662.933480] wlp2s0: associate with 80:da:13:1e:5e:63 (try 1/3)
Jul 12 16:59:24 moooo kernel: [ 4662.936498] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 80:da:13:1e:5e:63 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
Jul 12 16:59:24 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594594764.8871] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jul 12 16:59:24 moooo wpa_supplicant[1159]: wlp2s0: Associated with 80:da:13:1e:5e:63
Jul 12 16:59:24 moooo wpa_supplicant[1159]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jul 12 16:59:24 moooo wpa_supplicant[1159]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=US
Jul 12 16:59:24 moooo kernel: [ 4662.956563] wlp2s0: associated
Jul 12 16:59:24 moooo nm-applet[2838]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jul 12 16:59:24 moooo nm-applet[2838]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jul 12 16:59:24 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594594764.9068] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Jul 12 16:59:24 moooo io.elementary.s[12144]: network_widgets_settings_button_check_sensitive: assertion 'self != NULL' failed
Jul 12 16:59:24 moooo nm-applet[2838]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jul 12 16:59:24 moooo nm-applet[2838]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jul 12 16:59:24 moooo nm-applet[2838]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jul 12 16:59:24 moooo nm-applet[2838]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jul 12 16:59:28 moooo systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 12 16:59:28 moooo systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 884.
Jul 12 16:59:28 moooo systemd[1]: Stopped OpenVPN connection to server.
Jul 12 16:59:28 moooo systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN connection to server...
Jul 12 16:59:28 moooo ovpn-server[12157]: disabling NCP mode (--ncp-disable) because not in P2MP client or server mode
Jul 12 16:59:28 moooo ovpn-server[12157]: Options error: You must define TUN/TAP device (--dev)
Jul 12 16:59:28 moooo ovpn-server[12157]: Use --help for more information.
Jul 12 16:59:28 moooo systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 12 16:59:28 moooo systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 12 16:59:28 moooo systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenVPN connection to server.
Jul 12 16:59:29 moooo kernel: [ 4668.047687] wlp2s0: deauthenticated from 80:da:13:1e:5e:63 (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo wpa_supplicant[1159]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=80:da:13:1e:5e:63 reason=2
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo wpa_supplicant[1159]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <warn>  [1594594770.0546] sup-iface[0x5629e479b390,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason 2)
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594594770.0595] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594594770.1595] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo wpa_supplicant[1159]: wlp2s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 4c:01:43:ea:d4:06 (SSID='<ssid-name>' freq=2412 MHz)
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo kernel: [ 4668.790282] wlp2s0: authenticate with 4c:01:43:ea:d4:06
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo kernel: [ 4668.793823] wlp2s0: send auth to 4c:01:43:ea:d4:06 (try 1/3)
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594594770.7415] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo wpa_supplicant[1159]: wlp2s0: Trying to associate with 4c:01:43:ea:d4:06 (SSID='<ssid-name>' freq=2412 MHz)
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo kernel: [ 4668.797435] wlp2s0: authenticated
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo kernel: [ 4668.801401] wlp2s0: associate with 4c:01:43:ea:d4:06 (try 1/3)
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594594770.7534] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo kernel: [ 4668.806333] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 4c:01:43:ea:d4:06 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo wpa_supplicant[1159]: wlp2s0: Associated with 4c:01:43:ea:d4:06
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo wpa_supplicant[1159]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo wpa_supplicant[1159]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=US
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo kernel: [ 4668.826603] wlp2s0: associated
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594594770.7774] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo nm-applet[2838]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo nm-applet[2838]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo io.elementary.s[12144]: network_widgets_settings_button_check_sensitive: assertion 'self != NULL' failed
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo wpa_supplicant[1159]: wlp2s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 4c:01:43:ea:d4:06 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo wpa_supplicant[1159]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 4c:01:43:ea:d4:06 completed [id=0 id_str=]
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo kernel: [ 4668.851607] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594594770.8019] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594594770.8020] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network '<ssid-name>'.
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594594770.8021] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594594770.8027] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594594770.8098] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): dhclient started with pid 12178
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo nm-applet[2838]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo avahi-daemon[1144]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv6 with address fe80::aec8:966a:f5a:d3d0.
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo avahi-daemon[1144]: New relevant interface wlp2s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo avahi-daemon[1144]: Registering new address record for fe80::aec8:966a:f5a:d3d0 on wlp2s0.*.
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo nm-applet[2838]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo nm-applet[2838]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo dhclient[12178]: DHCPDISCOVER on wlp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x967ddf34)
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo nm-applet[2838]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jul 12 16:59:30 moooo io.elementary.wingpanel.desktop[2754]: Failed to register: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Jul 12 16:59:31 moooo wpa_supplicant[1159]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-30 noise=9999 txrate=1000
Jul 12 16:59:31 moooo dhclient[12178]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.4.39 on wlp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x34df7d96)
Jul 12 16:59:31 moooo dhclient[12178]: DHCPOFFER of 192.168.4.39 from 192.168.4.1
Jul 12 16:59:31 moooo dhclient[12178]: DHCPACK of 192.168.4.39 from 192.168.4.1
Jul 12 16:59:31 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594594771.8901] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   address 192.168.4.39
Jul 12 16:59:31 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594594771.8901] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   plen 22 (255.255.252.0)
Jul 12 16:59:31 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594594771.8902] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   gateway 192.168.4.1
Jul 12 16:59:31 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594594771.8902] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   lease time 14400
Jul 12 16:59:31 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594594771.8903] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   nameserver '75.75.75.75'
Jul 12 16:59:31 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594594771.8903] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   nameserver '75.75.76.76'
Jul 12 16:59:31 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594594771.8903] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed unknown -> bound
Jul 12 16:59:31 moooo avahi-daemon[1144]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.4.39.
Jul 12 16:59:31 moooo avahi-daemon[1144]: New relevant interface wlp2s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Jul 12 16:59:31 moooo avahi-daemon[1144]: Registering new address record for 192.168.4.39 on wlp2s0.IPv4.
Jul 12 16:59:31 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594594771.8968] device (wlp2s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 12 16:59:31 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594594771.8981] device (wlp2s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 12 16:59:31 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594594771.8986] device (wlp2s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 12 16:59:31 moooo dhclient[12178]: bound to 192.168.4.39 -- renewal in 6310 seconds.
Jul 12 16:59:31 moooo NetworkManager[1142]: <info>  [1594594771.9121] device (wlp2s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jul 12 16:59:31 moooo dbus-daemon[1086]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.17' (uid=0 pid=1142 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Jul 12 16:59:31 moooo systemd[1]: Starting resolvconf-pull-resolved.service...
Jul 12 16:59:31 moooo systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jul 12 16:59:31 moooo systemd[1]: Started resolvconf-pull-resolved.service.
Jul 12 16:59:31 moooo dbus-daemon[1086]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jul 12 16:59:31 moooo nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [wlp2s0]: new request (2 scripts)
Jul 12 16:59:31 moooo nm-applet[2838]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jul 12 16:59:31 moooo nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [wlp2s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Jul 12 16:59:31 moooo systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jul 12 16:59:31 moooo nm-applet[2838]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jul 12 16:59:32 moooo nm-applet[2838]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jul 12 16:59:32 moooo systemd-resolved[983]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 12 16:59:32 moooo systemd-resolved[983]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 12 16:59:32 moooo nm-applet[2838]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jul 12 16:59:32 moooo nm-applet[2838]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jul 12 16:59:32 moooo systemd[1]: Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Jul 12 16:59:32 moooo io.elementary.wingpanel.desktop[2754]: Failed to register: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Jul 12 16:59:32 moooo systemd[1]: Reloaded OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Jul 12 16:59:32 moooo nm-applet[2838]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jul 12 16:59:32 moooo systemd-resolved[983]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 12 16:59:32 moooo systemd-resolved[983]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 12 16:59:32 moooo systemd[1]: Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Jul 12 16:59:32 moooo nm-dispatcher[12213]: <15>Jul 12 16:59:32 CapNetAssist: DetectCaptivePortal script triggered
Jul 12 16:59:32 moooo CapNetAssist: DetectCaptivePortal script triggered
Jul 12 16:59:32 moooo systemd[1]: Reloaded OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Jul 12 16:59:32 moooo avahi-daemon[1144]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv6 with address fe80::aec8:966a:f5a:d3d0.
Jul 12 16:59:32 moooo avahi-daemon[1144]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv6 with address fdb1:da15:fb0b:1:e649:4d1f:6ecb:916d.
Jul 12 16:59:32 moooo avahi-daemon[1144]: Registering new address record for fdb1:da15:fb0b:1:e649:4d1f:6ecb:916d on wlp2s0.*.
Jul 12 16:59:32 moooo avahi-daemon[1144]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::aec8:966a:f5a:d3d0 on wlp2s0.
Jul 12 16:59:32 moooo avahi-daemon[1144]: Registering new address record for 2601:681:8700:79:f6a2:5126:a8ea:b500 on wlp2s0.*.
Jul 12 16:59:32 moooo systemd[1]: Starting resolvconf-pull-resolved.service...
Jul 12 16:59:32 moooo systemd[1]: Started resolvconf-pull-resolved.service.
Jul 12 16:59:33 moooo io.elementary.wingpanel.desktop[2754]: Failed to register: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Jul 12 16:59:33 moooo avahi-daemon[1144]: Registering new address record for 2601:681:8700:79:e92f:ff8e:5c9d:eea9 on wlp2s0.*.
Jul 12 16:59:33 moooo io.elementary.wingpanel.desktop[2754]: Failed to register: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Jul 12 16:59:33 moooo avahi-daemon[1144]: Registering new address record for fdb1:da15:fb0b:1:e92f:ff8e:5c9d:eea9 on wlp2s0.*.
Jul 12 16:59:34 moooo dbus-daemon[1086]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.148' (uid=1000 pid=12404 comm="nm-connection-editor --edit=83fe7325-fd21-3387-86c" label="unconfined")
Jul 12 16:59:34 moooo systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Jul 12 16:59:34 moooo gala.desktop[2739]: Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x3a00007 (Editing Wi)
Jul 12 16:59:34 moooo dbus-daemon[1086]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Jul 12 16:59:34 moooo systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
```

Comment: did you turn off some other device?

Comment: Actually, we're at the next morning, and the problem is right back where it started...I'll try the same thing I did yesterday (wired connect to the eero pro, then go to to Advanced Settings) while tailing my syslog and report what happened. to jsotola's point, no I don't believe any device was disconnected from the eero during that period. I tried several times yesterday to check if it was hitting some theoretical maximum connections and couldn't find any evidence that it was.